# How do I make now() be yesterday

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set dealend to be Yesterday instead of now. Is there a way to do it in this command line?

```
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, "UPDATE bookdeals SET dealend='now()' WHERE id='$pid'") or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
... SET dealend = now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note that with the `'now()'` you're using, you're not using a function called "now". You're trying to set your table field to be a string whose contents are the letters `n`, `o`, `w` etc.... Quotes turn things into strings and those things lose their specialty once they've been stringed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DATE_SUB`?

Comment: nope. you can use intervals in date math directly like that.

Comment: Actually CURDATE() worked for my situation, but this was the proper answer for the question I posed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

now() is a SQL function that is determined by the starting time of the transaction. You can changed the value of it by calling

```
SET TIMESTAMP = ...
```

However, for this to work it would need to be in the same transaction as your UPDATE query. What I would recommend instead is doing something like:

```
UPDATE bookdeals SET dealend=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAYS) WHERE id='$pid'
```

This uses the MySQL SUB_DATE() function, which will subtract one day from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL DATE_SUB function

```
... dealend=DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) ...
```

[Read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) for more information about MySQL date function